# Linear dependence and generalizing whether vectors in a given set are LD or LI (exercise from David Lay)

Tags: linear-algebra

When working on the linear dependence chapter from David Lay (section 1.7) I got to the following passage:

[image]

From my understanding, what is being said here is that you cannot **only** test one vector to see if it is a linear combination of the others, but all of them (one being a combination of the others is enough to make the set LD. So far so good.

Then I checked the Practice Problem 3 he was referring to (questions and answers below):

[image]

[image]

At this point, I got confused. Yes he does indeed state that only one vector not being a linear combination of the others is not enough. However, given that in this case we have four 3D vectors, we automatically have an LD set ($4 > 3$). For that reason, and this is my question, **can we state that at least one of the vectors u, v or z will be in the span of the other three vectors**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant idea here is the dimension of a space, which can be defined as the maximum number of linearly independent vectors in the vector space (among other equivalent definitions). For 3-dimensional vectors, the dimension is, as expected, 3. So any set of four (or more) vectors must be linearly dependent.

To answer your question, by definition this means that there exist scalars $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3, \alpha_4$, not all zero, such that $\alpha_1 u + \alpha_2 v + \alpha_3 w + \alpha_4 z = 0$. Since none of the vectors $u, v, w, z$ are zero, this means that at least two $\alpha_i, \alpha_j \ne 0$; by the pigeonhole principle, one of these, say $\alpha_i$, must belong to one of the vectors $u$, $v$, or $z$. Hence, we conclude that at least one of the vectors $u$, $v$, or $z$ must be in the span of the other three vectors (involving the other non-zero scalar $\alpha_j$ at least).